# UNET Performance of (many) Kinematic Rigidbodies

Tags: unity, c#, physics, unity-networking, unet

I am building a game in Unity in C# using the UNET networking elements.

I am trying to figure out **what is the performance cost of kinematic rigidbodies?**

My understanding is that, when kinematic, rigidbodies are outside the physics system and therefore are not as resource-heavy as non-kinematic rigidbodies.

For my game, I will need to use a lot of kinematic rigidbodies in the scene, because they are used to detect collisions between player-placed objects (with box colliders) and the rigidbodies. All the objects instantiated in the scene will therefore need a kinematic rigidbody to allow this collision checking to take place.

Thanks very much for your help.